# How to use Gmail as a repeater

Tags: gmail, email-rules

I am trialing "Google apps for your domain". I would like to use one address as a repeater for a club.

Forwarding only seems to work for one address but it looks like a rule will work.

Is it right that Gmail will only do this for verified addresses?

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Groups to achieve this, which at the most basic level are just mailing lists.

- Access your GAFYD control panel (e.g. https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourdomain.com/
- From the top navigation bar, select Users and Groups, then the Groups tab
- Create your new Group, if you just want to send emails out to the list, the "Announcement Only" would probably be the best option.

After you've created the Group, you get the option to enter the emails of members, which supports adding recipients from outside your domain.

Groups can go beyond traditional email distribution lists - they allow for a shared inbox, self-managed lists etc.  There seems to be plenty of online help describing all of this via the links from the group management page.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I needed.
Hadn't thought about that as I am used to contact groups in gmail

Answer (score 1):

Gmail will only forward to verified addresses.

It might be more appropriate to setup a mailing list, such as provided by [Yahoo group](http://groups.yahoo.com)s, where people can sign up and receive your updates in their inbox.

You send email to the group inbox, and it is sent to all the subscribers adresses. You can set it so that the owner is the only member allowed to send updates (newsletter)